# Problem with control ACTIVEX and Arctoolbox (9.3.1) on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, geoprocessing-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with ArcToolbox tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15565/problem-with-arctoolbox-tools)

"one or more activex controls could not be displayed 
when ever you try to open any tools from Arctoolbox it display this errors.

then go to start run -->regedit--> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Curre ntVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\ and delete the pseudonumeric key(L) or Rectangle shape before zone 0.

restart the arcgis , and it works"

Did anyone have ever tested this command, to resolve the problem in object?
What happens to the others programs and to OS?
Is it secure operation?